# Getting PendingMigrationError while running the Rails server on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ubuntu-14.04

I am getting the following error while running rails server on Ubuntu machine.

> Error:

```
ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError
Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
```

For resolving this issue i again run `rake db:migrate` but  got the below error.

> Error2:

```
== 20141218112307 DeviseCreateUsers: migrating ================================
-- create_table(:users)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `inet' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x00000008c00370>/home/subhrajyoti/100-Sallon/db/migrate/20141218112307_devise_create_users.rb:19:in `block in change'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:200:in `create_table'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:462:in `create_table'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:662:in `block in method_missing'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `block in say_with_time'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `say_with_time'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:652:in `method_missing'
/home/subhrajyoti/100-Sallon/db/migrate/20141218112307_devise_create_users.rb:3:in `change'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:606:in `exec_migration'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `block in migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:588:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:765:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:995:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1043:in `ddl_transaction'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:994:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:956:in `block in migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
NoMethodError: undefined method `inet' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x00000008c00370>
/home/subhrajyoti/100-Sallon/db/migrate/20141218112307_devise_create_users.rb:19:in `block in change'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:200:in `create_table'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:462:in `create_table'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:662:in `block in method_missing'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `block in say_with_time'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `say_with_time'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:652:in `method_missing'
/home/subhrajyoti/100-Sallon/db/migrate/20141218112307_devise_create_users.rb:3:in `change'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:606:in `exec_migration'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `block in migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:588:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:765:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:995:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1043:in `ddl_transaction'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:994:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:956:in `block in migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

> 20150121104519_add_facilities_to_businesses.rb:

```
class AddFacilitiesToBusinesses < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        add_column :businesses, :facilities, :string, array: true, default: []
        add_index :businesses, :facilities, using: 'gin'
    end
end
```

Actually i already have a Rails app which was with other database before and now i am trying it to connect `mysql` and getting these errors.I am using Rails version 4.2.0 and ruby 2.1.7.Please help me to resolve this errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error explain everything itself. You have problem in your database migration file. Go to `application_folder/db/migrate` and find file which contain name `devise_create_users.rb`.

Inside that file mistakenly you wrote `t.inte` which should be `t.integer`.

So try change `t.inte` to `t.integer` and you are done. If you get any other error in migration then follow [this](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html).

Remove gin from migration and run `rake db:migrate` again. gin specific for postgres indexing.

```
class AddFacilitiesToBusinesses < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        add_column :businesses, :facilities, :string, array: true, default: []
        add_index :businesses, :facilities
    end
end
```

Comment: First will automatically solved, Before start your server run migration first.

Comment: @ Dipak : Ok i will inform you.

Comment: @ Dipak : After creating some migration there is nor another error came which is `
Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'gin ON businesses(facilities)' at line 1: CREATE  INDEX index_businesses_on_facilities USING gin ON businesses(facilities) `  and i have posted the file in my post.Can you please correct this

Comment: @ Dipak : I got another error in same file which is Mysql::Error: Duplicate column name facilities: ALTER TABLE businesses ADD facilities varchar(255) DEFAULT '--- []\n'/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:299:in query' `

Comment: run `rake db:rollbak` and then run `rake db:migrate` again. If this not solve your problem then comment `add_column :businesses, :facilities, :string, array: true, default: []` line in your migration and run `rake db:migrate` again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89266/discussion-between-satya-and-dipak).